# Geometry - Cyclic Quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, circles, rectangles

Three points A,B,C lie on the circumference of the circle, with center as O. If angle(ACB) = 115 deg. Need to find angle (BOC)? Please post your approach?

Comment: You need at least the radius of the circle to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find the angle $BOC$, though you can find the angle $BOA$ which is $360^\circ-2\times115^\circ$

[image]

Comment: No wonder I was stuck. Thanks Henry. Can you tell me what if I have the value of the radius as, say 7 cm, does that make any difference, I doubt it does, need your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: No - the radius does not help